# Does a Pet Deposit change the meaning of Wear and Tear?

Tags: united-states, rental-property, minnesota, deposit

I am curious,  in a Rental Agreement there are the following stipulations for having pet(s) on the property:

- a non-refundable pet deposit be made (Payment)

  - I think I can safely assume this is for any damage that might occur from having a dog present on the property.
- a slight increase in the rent for a pet.

Do these preventative measures alter the Wear and Tear conditions under which a security deposit can be used for repairs?

1. can the Landlord take the money to repair normal wear and tear from having a pet in/on the property?